# VBA. What is incorrect in this code?

Tags: vba, kingsoft

Searching found code like this

```
Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnKey "+^{RIGHT}", "YourMacroName"
End Sub
```

However, when I tried, I got

[image]

How to create procedure?

I did this

```
Sub YourMacroName()
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("V").Select
End Sub

Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnKey "+^{RIGHT}", "YourMacroName"
End Sub
```

Got the same error

What would be correct code? Or where would be tutorial for dummies? Found some examples, but they does not work

I see my tags were modified to `excel` and `excel-vba`. But I do not use excel. Use Kingsoft Office

Changed `Application.OnKey "+^{RIGHT}", "YourMacroName"` to `.OnKey Key:="^+M", Procedure:="YourMacroName"`

and got

[image]

Then changed to `OnKey Key:="^+M", Procedure:="YourMacroName"` (removed `.`) and got error `Named argument not found`. And get selected `Key:=`

Comment: you don't have a procedure called "YourMacroName"

Comment: If Kingston Office is similar to Excel, then try to put `YourMacroName` inside a module instead of inside `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "ThisWorkbook", you will run code that is triggered by an event. I suggest you also put it in `Workbook_Open` instead of `Workbook_Activate` as you only need to store the shortcut once.

So, in the VB Editor, open the "Project Explorer" if it is not (CTRL+R) and find "ThisWorkbook" in the folder "Microsoft Excel Objects".
Here the code should look like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' CTRL + SHIFT + RIGHT
    Application.OnKey "+^{RIGHT}", "YourMacroName"

End Sub
```

Since, inside a Module (In the Project Explorer, right click on the folder "Modules" and select Insert > Module), put the macro "YourMacroName"

```
Sub YourMacroName()
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("V").Select
End Sub
```

Oh, and you should probably rename your procedure "YourMacroName" for something more obvious...